# Calling a dialog then goes back to page that called the dialog

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, dialog, cordova

I'm using jquery-mobile 1.3.0 and phonegap 2.8.0 calling a Dialog page from a button the thing is that a make a call as follow

```
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a" style="height: 0px; border: 0">
    <a id="btnHail" href="#confirm-address-dialog"  data-theme="e" data-rel="dialog">
                <i class="icon-phone"></i> Pedir Taxi
    </a>
</div>
```

But when it is call the first time the dialog appears but it goes back to the previous page. The code of the dialog is as follow:

```
<div data-role="page" id="confirm-address-dialog" data-theme="b">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="e">
            <h1> Titulo </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content" data-theme="b">
            <p>
                Are sure you want this?
            </p>
            <p>
                <b id="txtDataConfirm"></b>
            </p>
            <button id="btnHailConfirm" data-theme="e">
                <i class="icon-phone"></i> Ok
            </button>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" data-theme="a">
            <p>footer heading</p>
        </div>

</div>
```

This happen on an iPhone 4s (as developer) the problem never happen on chrome or mozilla. I have tried to use popups but there are some restriction with using popups that it doesn't show on my footer.

I appreciate for any help.

Comment: `data-role=dialog` not `page`

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't change anything. It's still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a lot of solutions but not of them worked. As I said before I didn't have any problem with the chrome or any browser on my desktop but on my iPhone it didn't work. What I found was the error was principally within the browser. So I set the configuration of the pushStateEnabled as false. I did it by doing the following, adding this script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
$.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
</script>
```

It should be add before the jquery-mobile script is call, for more information you could see it on [JQuery description](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-navmodel.html)

And it solved the problem no more jumping back.